# DependencyProperty in Custom Command

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to write a wrapper command class. I want use it like this

```
<Button Content="Test">
  <Button.Command>
    <local:FileOpenCommand Command="{Binding OpenFile}"/>
  </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

What I tried so far:

```
public class FileOpenCommand : FrameworkElement, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(FileOpenCommand),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged)
        {
            DefaultValue = new RelayCommand(
               (ob) => MessageBox.Show(ob.ToString()))
        });

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static void CommandChanged(
         DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { /* ... */ }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { /*...*/ }

    public event System.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            Command.Execute(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

This always shows the MessageBox from the `DefaultValue` command. The binding to `OpenFile` doesn't work. I get no BindingExpression errors but the `Openfile` Property is never called.

Edit: The MainWindow Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ICommand OpenFile
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(
                 (obj) => MessageBox.Show("I want to see this!")); }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems as though it should work , can you add the OpenFile Property , and how it is initialized ?

Comment: @eranotzer I added the code of the MainWindow of the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FileOpenCommand` is not part of the visual or logic tree, therefore you don't have a inherited `DataContext` and thus your `Binding` can't work. Try using `ElementName` or setting an explicit `Source`. Remember `RelativeSource` traverses the tree and won't work either. Add `PresentationTraceSources.TraveLevel=High` to check the actual problem for yourself.

But to be clear, why are you trying this anyway? Whats wrong with

```
<Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding OpenFile}">
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check this tomorrow. Your question: I liked the idea to separate the appearance of the file selectioN from the VM layer, but this was my Option if the command  wrapper wont work.

Comment: Remember its perfectly fine to call a command in a command, there is no special logic. So you could build a command which opens the file dialog and after a file was choosen, you fire the actual open command, which operates directly on the filename

Comment: I tried to use `ElementName` but I get *Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Btn'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.OpenFile;*. I think I will return a FileOpenCommand in `OpenFile` but would be nice to get this run anyway.